# What is the best practice to improve table performance?

Tags: mysql

In order to maintain tables and indexes efficiency it is not recommended to directly run "OPTIMYZE TABLE" (as stated in the link below), so is it best practice to do so in the following exact order?

1. DROP foreign keys (in order to drop related indexes)
2. DROP indexes (composite and non composites)
3. Perform OPTIMIZE TABLE
4. ADD INDEXES
5. ADD FOREIGN KEYS
6. ANALYZE TABLE

I believe this last step (analyze table) is also useful in order to update indexes cardinality within the information_schema.statistics table.

Any correction or further suggestions on this are welcome!

Thanks

link: https://www.percona.com/blog/2010/12/09/mysql-optimize-tables-innodb-stop/

example:

```
alter table T1 DROP  index i1 ;
alter table T1 DROP  index i2 ; 
optimize table T1 ; 
alter table T1 ADD  index i1(c1) ; 
alter table T1 ADD unique index i2(c1, c2) ; 
analyze table T1 ;
```

Comment: Way to broad to be answerd without knowing datatypes, number of columns or which queries are run ...

Comment: .. also that suggestion looks a bit wierd also at first seight what happens if updates / deletes / selects which needs that index happen right after dropping the index..  Those queries will run extremly slow besides the `optimize` then needs to wait to be run before those other queries are done..

Comment: ... i think i would go for [InnoDB 's online DDL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-online-ddl-operations.html) to "optimize"/rebuild the table and indexes instead , more or less like `ALTER TABLE table_name ENGINE=INNODB ALGORITHM=INPLACE, LOCK=NONE;` .. Also this does not lock the table **so the table stays accessible** as `OPTIMIZE/ANALYZE` would table lock but be warned this `ALTER` might be slower to finish then the method your are trying.. The plus side of it incoming queries will still run plus they can still use indexes

Comment: @RaymondNijland Can i add a "lock table" statement at the beginning of the script (and unlock at the end) to avoid other queries concurrency?

Comment: i assume you mean [LOCK TABLES and UNLOCK TABLES Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lock-tables.html)  ?    Be sure then you get a `READ` and `WRITE` lock and also unlock both..   Also be sure to read that section about using it with InnoDB..

Comment: Please be aware that the blog you are referring to is NINE years old.

Comment: I would suggest that many mention of `ALGORITHM` supersedes any mantion of `LOCK TABLES` in this context.

Answer (score 2):

Did you perceive any improvement?  I doubt it.  In most situations, InnoDB takes care of keeping its BTrees clean "enough".  Running an `OPTIMIZE TABLE` provides only a minor improvement for a short period of time.

There are other things to look at.  Examples:

- `index i1(c1)` is unnecessary since you also have `unique index i2(c1, c2)`.
- If you have `PRIMARY KEY(id)` consider upgrading that unique index to `PRIMARY KEY(c1, c2)`.
- `FOREIGN KEYs` cost something on every insert; do you really need them?
- Are you blindly using `BIGINT` when perhaps `SMALLINT` would suffice?